# Парсинг JSON без имени массива Android

Tags: java, android, json

С сайта парсится такой JSON:

```
{
    "1": "a",
    "2": "b",
}
```

Как получить значения эти значения, если у JSON нет имени?

Пытаюсь получить так, но не получается, не знаю, что писать в параметре `getJSONArray()`:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");

for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
JSONObject event = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

String value1= event.getString("1");
```

Comment: Почему вы решили что это массив? Предикатом массива в json является знак `[`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не массив, а поля корневого объекта :

```
String value1 = response.getString("1");
```

Если неизвестно их количество и/или имена - можно получить их в цикле:

```
for (String key : response.keys()) {
    String value = response.getString(key);
    Log.i(TAG, key + " = " + value);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но response не видит метода getKeys.

Comment: Опечатка: `response.keys()`

Comment: переменная `value` ничего не получает.

Comment: То есть ключи выводятся, а значения нет? Может они реально пустые?